# Expression Blend Forcing User Controls to be hidden

Tags: expression-blend

So I have been working on a project using C Sharp and WPF for a while now, and now recently several of my user controls are hidden in Expression Blend. I tried show all, setting visibility to Visible in the gui, cleaning the project build, rebuilding, restarting, etc... nothing seems to work.

As you can imagine, this is very frustrating, and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Which version of Expression Blend and Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Do you mean that they are not vibile at design time or when run from within Expression Blend?

Comment: If you could add your XAML that would help us to see, *or not see*, your invisible usercontrols too :)

Comment: @ChrisBD: Expression 3, Visual Studio 2010. They are not visible at design time (they were before), in other words I want to edit the design of a user control but I cannot, for it refuses to 'unhide'.
@HiTech Magic: The XAML contains no reference to visibility, though at runtime the visibility is turned on and off, but runtime works fine.

Comment: I'm glad that you've found a solution, but I'm surprised that you're using Expression 3 as it's not compatible with Visual Studio 2010 - don't fear though there is a free upgrade to Expression 4 from Microsoft or your volume licensing vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way around it. The problem is somehow related to the fact that I have several UserControls extended from a class that extends UserControl, but which has no XAML file itself.

Changing the xaml root from something like MyCustomUserControl temporarily to UserControl will allow the content to appear. Once done editing, change the root back so your program can run.